# Wrapfigs adds delta's to intertext

Tags: align, wrapfigure

I'm trying to use a wrapfig in my text an paragraph before an align*-envirement but by doing so, my intertexts all get a delta-sign.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{align*}
    W & = F \, d\\ 
    \Delta W & = q\vec{E} \cdot \Delta\vec{s}\\
\end{align*}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.69\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.68\linewidth]{../Foto's/Ele1.jpg}
\caption{Potentiaal en arbeid}
\label{potarb}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

Splits de veldsterkte in zijn componenten. Bedenk dat de component loodrecht op de verplaatsing geen arbeid uitvoert. Verduidelijking in figuur \ref{potarb}.

\begin{align*}
\Delta W & = q\vec{E_1} \cdot \Delta\vec{s} \\
& = qE_1 \Delta s \cos\alpha
\intertext{Daarna gaan we over naar de volledige tekening bij \ref{potarb}. Hierbij willen we berekenen welke arbeid wordt geleverd tussen A en B.}
W^{\textsc{b}}_{\textsc{a}}
&= \sum^{B}_A \Delta W\\
&= q \sum^B_A \vec{E_1} \cdot \Delta s\\
&= q \lim_{\Delta s \to 0} \sum^B_A \vec{E} \cdot \Delta s\\
&= q \int_A^B \vec{E} \cdot \, \vec{ds}\\
&= q \int_A^B \frac{Q \cos \alpha}{4 \pi \varepsilon r^2} \, ds\\
\intertext{We gaan over van ds naar dr. Zie figuur}
&= \frac{q Q}{4 \pi \varepsilon } \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \frac{1}{r^2} \, dr
\intertext{bedenk dat de integraal van een macht, \'e\'en over 'de nieuwe macht' maal de variabele tot de 'oude macht plus \'e\'en' wordt.}
& = \frac{q Q}{4 \pi \varepsilon } \left[-\frac{1}{r_b} - (-\frac{1}{r_a})\right]\\
&= \frac{q Q}{4 \pi \varepsilon } \left[\frac{1}{r_a} - \frac{1}{r_b}\right]\\
\intertext{ Per definitie is het potentiaalveschil V = $\frac{Q}{4 \pi \varepsilon r}$}
& = q(V_a-V_b)
\end{align*}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it in compatibility issue somewhere?

Comment: problem is confirmed.  (your example needs a `\begin ... \end{document}`, and a dummy figure to compile.)  `wrapfigure` is known to do strange things in the presence of environments that modify the paragraph shape, so this kind of interference isn't surprising.  by the way, the `\Delta` that shows up at the beginning of every `\intertext` line seems not to be related to the `\Delta`s in the aligned math, as can be demonstrated by replacing all those `\Delta`s by `\aleph`.

Comment: Hmm, okay. So basically I can't stop it from happening? And the only solution is to replace all my intertext with and \end{align*} and a \begin{align*} respectivelly before and after the intertext?

Comment: replacing all the `\intertext` with "ordinary" text and restating the `align*` environment would change the positioning of the math drastically.  `wrapfigure` modifies the apparent text width, allowing the first couple of aligned lines to occupy just a very narrow space.  those two lines are complete on their own, but the remainder of the math is a unit, so it should all be aligned.  just ending the alignment before the first intertext, changing that to an ordinary paragraph, and starting a new alignment doesn't work either -- the `\Delta`s are still there.

Comment: I have done exactly what you described and, it's not properly coded like you say, but it does work in my document. More or less. But it did kill the \Delta's. I did also add another picture which seems to have an impact. But I'm gonna close the topic. Thank you a lot for the information and the help Barbara. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, although there is clearly an incompatibility, the problem was avoided by a workaround.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Then the workaround should be posted as an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @SeanAllred -- notice that i said the "problem was avoided", not solved.  the output still isn't formatted as desired.  so i don't think that is a solution.  the "answer" is very likely to be that any multi-line math from `amsmath` is incompatible with `wrapfigure`, and like the latter's incompatibility with lists, is probably intractable.